# MYSQL database error

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me with this mysql code? It doesn't work.

```
REATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` int(10) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Saying "It doesn't work" is not nearly enough information to go on.

Comment: `REATE TABLE`? Could be one of those annoying "missing character" bugs.

Comment: Other thing I see - you cannot name your indexes `username,email` since those are the same as column names. They need to be unique like `idx_username`.

Comment: "it doesn't work"... hmmm, can you post the error you are getting (we're not in the mind-reading business yet)

Answer (score 0):

The answer looks simple till the time you dont mention the error. Try to use `create` not `reate`:-

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/984ef)

Comment: I didn't down voted you... yet. You are repeating the error present in the OP: the index names are the same as the column names, and that is not allowed. Name them something like `idx_username`, `idx_email`.

Comment: Ow I didn't see that! :D

Comment: Ok now I get this error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
' at line 9

Comment: @smovie9:- Missed the comma. Updated the answer with the SQL Fiddle. I am sure it will work. P.S. Dont forget to accept this as an answer if it helped

Comment: Ok thnx for the ansers!